# A parsimonious large cardinal axiom

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

The ordering of large cardinals by consistency strength is well known.
I was wondering what one can say regarding an ordering by direct implication.
In particular, I am looking for is a parsimonious axiom of the form "There exists an XYZ cardinal" which 'picks up' as many other large cardinals as possible by *directly implying* that they exist.

So the best I can think of is:
Extendible cardinal $\implies$ Supercompact cardinal $\implies$ Measurable cardinal $\implies$ Loads of other large cardinals  (There are also many other in between these categories that are directly implied, I believe)

But is it possible to go further ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you are asking. A table with all known large cardinals and for any two of them a decision on whether or not the existence of one kind of cardinal implies the existence of the other?

Comment: [I0 cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-into-rank)?

Comment: See also https://MathOverflow.net/questions/219132